# Determine how a popup window is closed

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I need to perform different actions based on the way a popup window is closed.

I assume there are two ways to close a popup window:

- Click the close button on the popup window
- use `window.close` function

Is there a way to determine which way is used when a popup window closes?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, no. **[Relevant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/261083/is-there-a-way-to-determine-that-the-browser-window-was-closed)**.

Detecting the browser closing at all is hairy, let alone detecting *how* it was closed.

Answer (score 1):

try this..

```
var myWindow = window.open('yourpage.php','test page','width=640,height=480');
var newwindow = false;
myWindow.onunload = function() {
    if (myWindow.closed) {
        alert("Window Closed by Your function");
    } else if(myWindow && newwindow){
        alert("Window Closed by close button");
    } else{
        newwindow = true;
    }
};
```

the `newwindow` variable used to handle the `onunload` function executed during opening the window.