# How distinguish refresh and close event using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, events, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way in javascript to detect if the unload event is caused via a refresh, the back button, or closing the browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291553/is-there-a-way-in-javascript-to-detect-if-the-unload-event-is-caused-via-a-refres)

Hi all

I have the below set of code

```
$(window).unload( function() {
   test();
});
```

the test() will call when i close the window and also if i refresh the window ..... How can identify is it a `refresh` or `close` event . I need to call `test()` only at close event. Please help me...

Comment: Sorry, not possible, as has been determined before. For example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/291553/is-there-a-way-in-javascript-to-detect-if-the-unload-event-is-caused-via-a-refres

Comment: Be careful with the unload event - It might not work properly in some browsers.