# How to capture the browser window close event on PHP?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I found the code below in stackoverflow and it works fine, but how can I capture `<input type="button">`?

I tried `$('input').on('click')`, `$('input.button').on('click')`, and `$('button').on('click')` also didn't work. Also is there any method to capture refresh event? Many thanks.

```
var inFormOrLink;
$('a').on('click', function() { inFormOrLink = true; });
$('form').on('submit', function() { inFormOrLink = true; });

$(window).on("beforeunload", function() { 
    return inFormOrLink ? "Do you really want to close?" : null; 
})
```

Comment: How about giving the button an id and select the id.

Comment: Why tag this as `php`? I believe this is can be solved through `javascript` alone, or am I missing a point?

Comment: what is it that you want to do exactly? capture refresh event? capture onclick event? or capture window close event?

Comment: Gideon, sorry... it should javascript only

Comment: I want to capture window close, once user confirm close the window then perform php function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To capture click on the `<input type="button">` you can do

```
$('input[type=button]').on('click', function() {});
```

To capture refresh event you can do

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {};
```

To capture refresh event with jQuery you can use [unload](https://api.jquery.com/unload/)

```
$(window).unload(function() {});
```

Comment: but how to know the windows unload is refresh but not close window ? thanks.

Comment: As far as I know it might be possible, but not that trivial to implement. I'd rather reconsider your architecture, but if you really need to differentiate between refresh and close you better check out some existing questions for that. LIke this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/291553/is-there-a-way-in-javascript-to-detect-if-the-unload-event-is-caused-via-a-refre or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/568977/identifying-between-refresh-and-close-browser-actions/13916847#13916847

Answer (score 0):

If I get you correctly, you want to know when a tab/window is effectively closed. Well, AFAIK the only way in Javascript to detect that kind of stuffs are onunload & onbeforeunload events.

Unfortunately (or fortunately?), those events are also fired when you leave a site over a link or your browsers back button. So this is the best answer I can give, I don't think you can natively detect a pure close in Javascript. Correct me if I'm wrong here.