# Javascript refresh triggered or intentional?

Tags: javascript, page-refresh

If a user clicks refresh or does f5 or refreshes by tab left click/reload then it is an intentional action!

Can a hacker inject a script maybe in an image src (but not to be too specific;) or anywhere else on the page, that forces a reload/redirect?

If so, is there something in the onbeforeunload event that will tell me that this was **triggered** by code?

### **WOW**

```
window.onunload=function(e){console.dir(e);}
location.reload();
Event
Navigated to https://www.google.com/webhp?hl=en
```

Proof that [Kaii](https://stackoverflow.com/users/43959/kaii) is correct! I wonder why browser venders don't make an object of this event - to at least check if a refresh was user intention???

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291553/is-there-a-way-in-javascript-to-detect-if-the-unload-event-is-caused-via-a-refre

Comment: not really dude, I vaguely remember doing code a while back where the browser (I think it was chrome) knew that I was jquery triggering a button rather than clicking it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can a hacker inject a script maybe in an image src (but not to be too specific;) or anywhere else on the page, that forces a reload/redirect?

Yes, i.e.:

```
<script>window.location = window.location;</script>
```

> If so, is there something in the onbeforeunload event that will tell me that this was triggered by code?

No. The event object observable during `onbeforeunload()` does not contain any trace of information about the cause of unloading.

Comment: Thanks! Your last sentence is only one word long so have to ask you how do you know that you are correct? (you are stating a fact) have you console.dir(event) ? if so how? I would like to do this

Comment: @BenMuircroft in the firebug console there is a "persist" button, so the console isn't cleared on page reload. issue `window.onbeforeunload = function (evt) { console.log(evt); };` directly followed by `window.location = window.location;` to inspect the event properties.

Comment: Dude, I just tested +1 updated my question because I can't understand why browser vendors would leave such a security hole!?