# How to distinguish Unload Event triggered by Refresh or Window Close?

Tags: javascript, events, refresh

Unload Event can be triggered both by Refresh action and Window Close action. is there a way to distinguish which action that actually trigger it? In my situation, i want to ignore the Refresh action. Could you please give me some insight what the work around is?

I noticed that there is already this sort of [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/568977/identifying-between-refresh-and-close-browser-actions) asked, but it seems to they are all unresolved. Therefore i came up this question again and hopefully some intelligent guy can solve this problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I do not believe the browser can distinguish between the two events.

Both are an `unload` event, and both will call any `unload` function that you have made.

Comment: Does this answer hold true till date?

Comment: I believe so @NicholasK