# Fire function if visitor tries to close browser window by clicking "x" button

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, browser

What I want to do is, to fire some function, only when user tries to close browser window by clciking on x button. But not on refresh, "back" button click events like following function does.

```
$(window).unload( function () { alert("Bye now!"); } );
```

So is there any way to achieve this? Thx in advance

Comment: I don't think it's possible to distinguish those actions.

Comment: Try using JavaScript to open your page in a new window, and use [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/781770/can-the-parent-window-be-notified-when-a-child-window-closes-on-a-diff-domain) to detect when it's closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try forcing the user to a default location hash of #default as soon as they load the page. Then, if the person navigates back with the back button you can detect this with either a timer or the window's "popstate" event. Then, you could do something at this point like send them to another url.

In this way you could detect a window CLOSE with the "onbeforeunload" event and a back button press with the method mentioned in the last paragraph. Messy but it works.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible. The `onbeforeunload` event does something like this but that will always fire when the windows closes. It does not differentiate between the way in which the window got unloaded.

Answer (score 1):

Couple of answers pointing that you won't be able to achive this:
[How to distinguish Unload Event triggered by Refresh or Window Close?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3115773/how-to-distinguish-unload-event-triggered-by-refresh-or-window-close)
and 
[How to distinguish Unload Event triggered by Refresh or Window Close?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3115773/how-to-distinguish-unload-event-triggered-by-refresh-or-window-close)
Both "workarounds" suggested are checking out mouse position and asking akinator.