# How to differentiate refresh page and close page function onunload

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need a help with this function `onunload`.

What I want is  to differentiate those events close window and refresh page on Internet 
Explorer and Firefox because on Google Chrome work fine.

To explain the issue, when I close a window and refresh a page on Internet Explorer or Firefox the function `onunload` is called; but in Google Chrome, only when you close windows.

Also I use the event `onbeforeunload` but the same issue occurs.

So the question is, how can I differentiate those event in Firefox and Internet Explorer?
Is this possible?

I will be grateful with your help or some information about this issue.

Comment: create a jsfiddle for the problem.

Comment: lol you cant create a fiddle for that or that would be weird. maybe it could be possible to check timestamps using cookies?

Comment: I don't understand what you say... please could both of you explain better or more easily your reply?
Many Thanks.

Comment: this link might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4387212/differentiate-between-f5-and-browser-close-event-in-flex-actionscript