# calling javascript function once on body onload event

Tags: php, javascript

I am currently working on the project that have 2 php files category.php and product.php.

In category.php file i put a link shown below.

```
<a href="product.php?cat=getcate" class="option">click here</a>
```

I have the following js function called on the body onload in the product.php page.

```
<body onload="font_select(1760,'No',239)">
```

When users click on the link then they will be redirect to product.php file where the body onload function is called.this function is working fine.

My question is i need to call this function only once when the user enter in product.php page.currently this function is called on page reload also.

How would i call this function only once ? Thanx In Advance.

Comment: Is there a difference between those events?

Comment: https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=1395489

Answer (score 3):

The most efficient way will be, use [Cookies](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html)

Answer (score 0):

(It's a little kludgy, but you could check document.referrer in font_select)
well that's wrong, turns out at least in firefox the referrer does not change apparently when the page is refreshed.

You may want to have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004978/check-if-page-reloaded-or-refresh-in-js), where they handle detecting refresh using a cookie, however you should know that is really just a check if the page has been accessed before so it won't work unless you also clear that cookie on detecting a click on the link from your category.php page.

Answer (score 0):

Go for [javascript cookies](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp)

well to track whether the function is called or not, you could use javascript cookie. Like say you set a cookie with any name, say `functioncalled` with value 0 initially, when user goes to product page, check this cookie. If value is 0, then call a function then set the value of cookie to 1, next time when page is reloaded the function will not be called.