# Session Expire on Browser Refresh button

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

Do you have any idea on how to expire the Session on Browser Refresh button only in asp.net. Thanks. You can also provide your responses in C# or Js or Jquery...

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. This is not a [real question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145677/what-is-a-real-question) for here. Did you try anything so far? Show your effort first so people might show their. Please read [FAQ] and [ask]

Comment: browser refresh button repeats the previous request (assuming there was no ajax request in between) per my knowledge i don't know of a way to flag the refresh with any other attributes to create a special request.

Comment: I really don't have an idea. So I didn't place the code.

Comment: Why would you want to do this?  It sounds like there is something else incorrectly structured in your code.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? It's not a common behaviour for a web application.

Answer (score 1):

in c# use:

```
Session.Abandon();
```

This will clear all session and assign new session key and `Session_OnEnd()` event will also be fired.

**Logic to check if page is refreshed**

If you want to check the page is refreshed or not, then you can use cookies for that matter.

Store a cookie when page is visited first time. On refresh, check if your cookie exists or not.

see: [Check if page gets reloaded or refreshed in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004978/check-if-page-reloaded-or-refresh-in-js)

based on this you can apply clear session when your page is refreshed.

Here is code for reference:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if(document.cookie.indexOf('mycookie')==-1) {
    // this mean cookie doesn't exist and user visited first time
    document.cookie = 'mycookie=1';//set the cookie to check for next time
  }
  else {
    // cookie is not null i.e. page is refreshed, 
    //So, make an ajax call to handler and use Session.Abandon() on handler in c# code.
  }
});
```

**Also, when browser will be closed, cookie will be automatically cleared.**

Comment: I know how to abandon a session. I want to clear the session only on Browser refresh button...

Comment: First check your page is refreshed or not by the help of cookies, if so, then use an ajax call to handler that clear session.

Comment: How would you know the Page is refreshed instead of visited for a second time?

Comment: @Dynan, if cookie is not null then page is refreshed! See my edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
//this will solve the postback part (button click). 
//The refresh you should handle with querystring params
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
  if(Page.IsPostBack)
     Session.Abandon();
}
```

Comment: Page.IsPostBack will be evaluated to false when refresh is done. This is used to know when postback is done, not to know if refresh is done.

Comment: I know that. Did you read the comment in my code?