# alternative jquery library to triger beforeunload/unload event

Tags: javascript, jquery

**edit**: As my question seems unclear - all i want is to add `confirm()` message whenever the user leaves the page by closing browser/typing new link/clicking existing link

I've read a lot of topics concerned beforeunload/unload events, but none of those actually could helped me, may be i'm doing smth wrong.

I have the script working by clicking all the links, however 'beforeunload' event does not work in my situation

**normal script**

```
$('a').on('mousedown', function(){
    var message = 'You are about to leave the page. Continue?'
    var result = confirm(message)
    if (result) {
        // some stuff
    } else {
        // some other stuff
    }
})
```

**trying with beforeunload**

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function(){
    var message = 'You are about to leave the page. Continue?'
    var result = confirm(message)
    if (result) {
        // some stuff
    } else {
        // some other stuff
    }
})
```

And nothing is happening. I've tried unload event too, but still no luck.

Comment: Following your edit, you can only return a string from onbeforeunload event. This will prompt a confirm box. Be aware, FF doesn't allow custom message AFAIK. Anyway, you could reach many other issues using this event, you should avoid it whenever possible

Comment: are there any alternative libraries to implement confirm dialog on closing browser etc. ?

Comment: @skzd This isn't a jQuery feature, but a javascript feature.  No javascript library will allow you to call `confirm()` with a `beforeunload` event.

Comment: Event's behaviour depend of browsers implementation, nothing javascript can do. If any library could modify it in any way, it would be already massively abused, and then, should be fixed ASAP...

Comment: so can i at least listen for certain events like clicking or closing window and then call my function with confirm message?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`beforeunload` events are a little odd.  Most browsers won't allow you to trigger a confirm dialogue from the handler since that would allow the site to continuously pop up confirm dialogues rather than navigating away from the page.  Instead, you should return the message you want to display, for example:

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function(e) {
    var msg = 'You are about to leave the page.  Continue?';
    (e || window.event).returnValue = msg;  //IE + Gecko
    return msg;  //Webkit
});
```

If you want to run additional javascript after the resultant dialogue has exited, add an `onunload` listener.

**EDIT**

As is pointed out in the comments, these events differ from browser to browser.  For example, the latest version of gecko (firefox) does not allow custom messages.

Comment: Are you sure that will work? Also note you have a syntax error at the end. Here is the docs page where the code snippet originated (using `window.addEventListener`): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/beforeunload

Comment: `onunload` and `onbeforeunload` can have inconsistent behaviour accross browser, e.g, FF doesn't allow custom message (lastest version???) and onunload event could not be fired (opera?), etc... Now rereading OP's question, i think this answer the question +1