# How to Detect Page Refresh in IE, caused by refresh button and Context Menu ?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, internet-explorer, html

I need to control the page behavior when user click on IE refresh button or from right click -> refresh. 
Is it possible to detect these action , if yes How?

Comment: You can detect someone *leaving* a page (even if they are simply refreshing it in their browser); is that sufficient?

Comment: No that will not perform the task, as user can leave the page due to post back also, so only in this specific scenario I want to refresh the page with some url changes. In HTML 5 we can change the url firectly, but as we still supporting IE8, so before refreshing I need to put Hash value in URL. Please suggest.

Comment: In which case, what you're after isn't possible. Note that both the answers you've had so far don't meet this requirement.

Comment: yes, please guide how to do that ?

Comment: will have a look...n let u know.. thanks :)

Comment: Is the link works? ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18457797/how-to-know-whether-refresh-button-or-browser-back-button-is-clicked-in-firefox  is an approach I can follow.. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can perform you actions before reloading with
    - OnBeforeUnload().

Answer (score 0):

```
 window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
e = e || window.event;
// For IE and Firefox prior to version 4
if (e) {
    e.returnValue = 'Are you sure? You will lose unsaved changes.';
}
// For Safari
return 'Are you sure? You will lose unsaved changes.';
};
```

here is the snippet which checks the reload functionality on a page.

Regards

Comment: *loose* - not firmly or tightly fixed. *lose* - to cease to have.

Comment: i don't get what you mean by loose ?

Comment: You've used the word "loose" in your prompts; the word you're after is "lose". It's a very common error.