# Unexpected performace.navigation.type onbeforeunload

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, onbeforeunload

I'm trying to handle some logic on before unload and I don't want that logic to run if the user is reloading the page or going back.

I've set up something like this.

```js
window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
  if(window.event && window.event.clientX){ //IE
    //some logic
  } else if (e.currentTarget.performance.navigation.type === e.currentTarget.performance.navigation.TYPE_RELOAD) {
     // another logic
  } else if(e.currentTarget.performance.navigation.type === e.currentTarget.performance.navigation.TYPE_BACK_FORWARD){
     // yet another logic
  }
}
```

I have other code to handle refresh and such from keyboard input that all seems to be working ok. Right now I'm concerned with this piece of code. For some reason on the first reload or back button the navigation.type comes back as 0, but after that all other reloads or back buttons populate the correct value in navigation.type. Even in IE on the first reload something is not being set correctly (not sure if its the mouse location or what yet). What could be causing something like this?

Comment: Even while closing a browser's tab, performance.navigation.type gives you 1 (performance.navigation.TYPE_RELOAD)! Can we actually detect the browser is about to refresh?

Comment: can you detect STOP RELOAD ? cross button after reload?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, I think what you wanted to write was `e.currentTarget.performance.navigation.type` (not `e.current.performance.navigation.type`), which is the same as writing `window.performance.navigation.type`. This variable tells you how this page was navigated *to*, not the type of navigation that the page is exiting through.

Why you get `performance.navigation.type` as `0` (`performance.navigation.TYPE_NAVIGATE`) the first time is that the page *was* loaded by direct navigation that first time. Subsequent reloads will set `performance.navigation.type` to 1 (`performance.navigation.TYPE_RELOAD`) because the page is **now** loaded *by* reloading. So, you are getting the method that was used to load the page, not the method that the user is using to exit the page.

Comment: ah well that explains it. Is there no way to determine the method used to leave the page?

Comment: Even while closing a browser's tab, performance.navigation.type gives you 1 (performance.navigation.TYPE_RELOAD)! Can we actually detect the browser is about to refresh?