# How to detect a page is reloaded by anchor tag or not?

Tags: javascript

I have a page (index.html) and it is looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="index.html" target="_top" >reload</a>
</body>
</html>
```

When a user clicks on anchor tag then index.html reload due to the same reference of the page **href="index.html"**.

So, is there any way to check whether a user clicks on anchor tag or reload by another way like by pressing F5 Key or pragmatically (window.location.reload()).

Edit:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(){
 // how to capture here 
}
```

Comment: `href="#?anchor=true"` would do.

Comment: Add an `onclick` event handler on `a` tag?

Comment: `href="#"` wouldn't make the page reload. It would just scroll to the top.

Comment: the best thing to do is probably a `window.onbeforeunload` check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18457797/how-to-know-whether-refresh-button-or-browser-back-button-is-clicked-in-firefox

Comment: Thanks @Turnip to correct me.

Answer (score 1):

As for window.onbeforeunload you can do this:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault = true;
    e.cancelBubble = true;
    e.returnValue = 'test';
}
```

As for Bootstrap and FontAwesome try:

CSS:

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div id="modalId" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title"><span>Page Loader</span></h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Please wait...</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
  e = e || window.event;
  e.preventDefault = true;
  e.cancelBubble = true;
  $('.modal-body').append('<span class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin" aria-hidden="true"></span>')
  $('#modalId').modal('show');
};
```