# Is there jquery refresh button event handler?

Tags: jquery, events, refresh, handler

I found the way to refresh my article `div` with the following code when pressing `F5`. Only article part of `div` is replaced with a new content.

[image]

However, pressing browser's refresh button shows article `div` as a new page. It's not embedded in the main page.  This is not what I want. I want only the `div` refreshed like when pressing `F5`.

Is there any jquery event handler for the browser refresh button only?

Comment: Add your code in editable formats. Not like images...

Comment: Possible duplicates of:-[How to know whether refresh button or browser back button is clicked in firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18457797/how-to-know-whether-refresh-button-or-browser-back-button-is-clicked-in-firefox)

Comment: Or:- https://api.jquery.com/unload/

Comment: To refresh content of your particular div, use AJAX.

Comment: The solutions suggested before pop up confirm window. I just want to refresh sub div in main page without popup, when pressing refresh button. As for F5, I know how to deal.  thank you all anyway!!

Answer (score 0):

Try like following

```
<div id="div">content 1</div>

$(function(){
    $(document).keydown(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#div').load(" #div", function(){
            $(this).children().unwrap();
        });
        return (e.which || e.keyCode) == 116;
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi Anfather thanks, but it still works for F5 button only. When I press refresh button on browser, ariticle div opens as a new page like before.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to block refresh button from javascript/jquery, there is a way to block by changing setting in firefox browser, but it will only work on your system, hence not recommended. The best way is to use AJAX, that is the standard way of working when you don't want the page to reload.

Comment: Yes, there seems to be no way to intecept refresh button in code. I should find another way by using AJAX as you recommend, thank you!