# How can I stop this function on refresh Javascript

Tags: javascript

How can I stop this event from occurring on browser refresh? Here is the code:

```
if ($("body").attr('onbeforeunload') == null) {
if (window.event) {
    // IE and Chrome use this
    $("body").attr('onbeforeunload', 'CatchLeavePage(event)');
    <?php

    // Log out when browser is closed
    echo "  location.href=\"/logout.php\"";

    ?>      
}
```

How can I stop this event from occurring on browser refresh?

Comment: you can't. leaving and refreshing is the same thing for browsers.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004978/check-if-page-reloaded-or-refresh-in-js

Comment: the event will still trigger, that solution is to detect if a page opened from a refresh I believe, correct?

Answer (score 0):

Use a cookie or local storage to store a value that you have already done what you want to do.  Then if you want to do it again, just set that value to false.