# How to make jquery mobile site redirect to default page on reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm constructing a jQuery mobile site which has some subpages of the form

```
<div data-role="page" id="page1" data-theme="c">
...
</div>

<div data-role="page" id="page2" data-theme="c">
...
</div>
```

I would like to force any reload of the website (like pressing when F5), no matter in which subpage (e.g. `https://myurl/site#page2`) the current location is, to redirect to the login page (#mainPage) instead of reloading the same subpage.

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: So once the person has successfully logged in and if he refreshes the page for some reason, he should still be taken back to the login page.Is that right?

Comment: Dont really know why you would want to do this, but this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004978/check-if-page-reloaded-or-refresh-in-js might  help you and check on LocalStorage as well.

Comment: @manraj82: That's correct. I know it sounds weird, but the login page also includes some session information that might have changed..