# Javascript - How to run part of the code only after the page refreshes?

Tags: javascript, wordpress

**Important**: Even though this could probably be done with php (I'm using WooCommerce on Wordpress), I want this script to run only on my browser. That's why I want to do it in Javascript. Hence, I'm using [Custom Javascript for Websites](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/custom-javascript-for-web/poakhlngfciodnhlhhgnaaelnpjljija?hl=en) to load my script from my browser.

**What my script should do**: Check if the data of a specific element has been changed.

**Logic**: Step 1) Get and locally remember specific string (order number) of a specific class. Step 2) Refresh the page. Step 3) Again get the specific string (order number) of a specific class. Step 4) If strings do not match, run a function (play an audio).

**Problem**: After page reloads, the script starts to run again from the beginning. Hence, it results in overriding the stored string. As a result, stored and newly fetched string are always equal.

**Question**: How do I make the script to run the 3rd step only after refresh so that the stored data doesn't override itself?

**Current code**:

```
var OrderIdOld = document.getElementsByClassName("row-title"); // Select every single element with ClassName "row-title"
var x = (OrderIdOld[0].innerText); // Get the string of the first element of the class "row-title"
var compareOld = x.slice(-1); // Get the last element of the string (since it will be a number, we can change the string into a number easily later)
localStorage.setItem("compareOld", compareOld); // Store this element in local storage, so that it can be used after page reloads.

setInterval ("window.location.reload()", 30000); // Reload page every 30 secs.

var remembered = localStorage.getItem("compareOld"); // Assign stored element to a new var.
var n = compareOld.valueOf(); // Turn stored element into a number (for easy comparison later).

var OrderIdNew = document.getElementsByClassName("row-title"); // Select every single element with ClassName "row-title"
var y = (OrderIdNew[0].innerText); // Get the string of the first element of the class "row-title"
var compareNew = y.slice(-1); // Get the last element of the string (since it will be a number, we can change the string into a number easily later)
var m = compareNew.valueOf(); // Turn fetched element into a number (for easy comparison later).


function beep() {
    var snd = new  Audio("data:audio/wav;base64,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");  
    snd.play();
} // Function that will play the sound.


if (n!=m) {
beep();
} // Run function if two numbers are not equal.
```

**Additional**: I have gathered the parts of the code from various Questions on stackoverflow. Meaning, I have been searching about this topic for the past week. **This is my first questions ever**. Hopefully I formatted the question so that it easy to understand.

**EDIT**: The issue has been solved. I used the idea of only running the first step of function on the first load of page. This post helped me to get functionality working https://stackoverflow.com/a/22334768/7929506

**The working code looks like this**:

```
function beep() {
window.open('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EQ3zPIj2O5k','_blank');
}

if (sessionStorage.getItem("visit") == null) {
    var OrderIdOld = document.getElementsByClassName("row-title")[0].innerText.slice(-1).valueOf();
    sessionStorage.setItem("OrderIdOld", OrderIdOld);
    sessionStorage.setItem("visit", new Date());
    setTimeout("window.location.reload()", 10000);
}

else {
    var OrderIdNew = document.getElementsByClassName("row-title")[0].innerText.slice(-1).valueOf();
    var x = sessionStorage.getItem("OrderIdOld");
    if (x==OrderIdNew) {
        setTimeout("window.location.reload()", 10000);
        }
    else {
        beep();
        var x = sessionStorage.getItem("OrderIdOld");
        sessionStorage.removeItem("OrderIdOld");
        sessionStorage.removeItem("visit");
        setTimeout("window.location.reload()", 10000);
    }
}
```

Comment: Take a look at [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage). This will allow you yo easily save data between refresh, which you can use to define your state.

Comment: This question is very broad. Zou could use a cookie or HTML5 Web Storage, but I think, this is not a specific, reproducable problem.

Comment: @EmilS.Jørgensen I am using localStorage but it gets overriden after page refresh.

Comment: Maybe you are overwriting `compareOld` before you read what's in it? It looks like that's what's happening in line 4 and 8 of your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you refresh the page first time, you can simply append a flag variable to URL to identify weather its a refresh or a first time load. Based on that, you can pass a localized variable to script and if that is set then you need to refresh else not.

Comment: I used your suggestions as the main logic for the code. I updated the final code in the original question.

Comment: Great! As this helped, you can accept it and upvote it!

Comment: I did  but since my reputation is 1, it doesn't display.