# clear local storage variable after browser restart

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I have the following variable `localStorage.timesDisplayed` in the browser's local storage.

I am wondering if there is a way to clear that variable with Javascript when browser is restarted.

I can use : `delete localStorage.timesDisplayed` to delete the variable, but I am not sure how to detect that the browser has been restarted on the page load.

Comment: can you just clear it out on page load? also why use local storage for a temporary value? don't you want a plain variable for that?

Comment: You're probably changing the `localStorage` to `sessionStorage` as it automatically does exactly what you want to do.

Comment: @Buzinas on F5, session storage is maintained.

Comment: @DanielA.White but that's exactly what he wants. He want to delete the variable when the browser is *restarted*, and not when the page is *reloaded*.

Comment: yes, that's what I want.. I want to keep the variable alive on page load. But delete it only on browser restart (not page reload)

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/53307588/2828611, this might answer your question

Answer (score -3):

You could use sessionStorage instead. It will clear when the user exits your site.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage

Comment: This is not true. Despite its name, sessionStorage does NOT clear automatically when you close your browser.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage tells: "Closing a tab/window ends the session and clears objects in sessionStorage".  But sessionStorage may not fit if you want to share data between tabs.