# Redirecting to a different URL upon refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, url

So I want my page to redirect to a different page when the user refreshes the page. I want the user to be redirected to `index.html` from `gettingstarted.html` when he/she refreshes the page.

CODE:

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    //meta, seo stuff

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">

</head>
<body>

   //body stuff

   //below is just a script that redirects to gettingstarted.html upon first visit

  <script type="text/javascript">

    function redirect(){
    var thecookie = readCookie('doRedirect');
    if(!thecookie){window.location = 'http://domain.tld/gettingstarted.html';
    }}function createCookie(name,value,days){if (days){var date = new Date();date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();}else var expires = "";document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";}function readCookie(name){var nameEQ = name + "=";var ca = document.cookie.split(';');for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++){var c = ca[i];while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);}return null;}window.onload = function(){redirect();createCookie('doRedirect','true','999');}

  </script>

</body>
```

gettingstarted.html

Pretty much the same thing as `index.html`

I tried Googling but I kept getting the "Meta Refresh Tag" which in this case, is useless.

Comment: Do you mean like manually when a user reloads the page so he/she should be redirected to some another link??

Comment: yes @UmairShahYousafzai

Comment: you may refer this url [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004978/check-if-page-reloaded-or-refresh-in-js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004978/check-if-page-reloaded-or-refresh-in-js)

Comment: Code to detect the Refresh button or Close button is only by adding this code in your code `window.event.clientX >= 1300`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do what you're asking, just customize the URL.

```
<script>
if (sessionStorage.getItem('beenhere') ==='1') {
    window.location="http://www.example.com";
}
sessionStorage.setItem('beenhere', '1');
</script>
```

See:

See: [Check if page gets reloaded or refreshed in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004978/check-if-page-reloaded-or-refresh-in-js)

Answer (score 0):

Well..You can do it something like this way as :

```
if ( document.referrer == null || document.referrer.indexOf(window.location.hostname) < 0 ) {
sessionStorage.setItem("is_reloaded", true);
}
// This one will set the sessionStorage.setItem on first visit

if (sessionStorage.getItem("is_reloaded")) {
location.href = 'http://domain.tld/gettingstarted.html';
}
//Next time then if someone reload the page so it will reload the user to that another link
```

If the first one doesn't work so try this one as :

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
  location.href = 'http://domain.tld/gettingstarted.html';
};
```

Comment: doesn't work... just automatically redirects @UmairShahYousafzai

Comment: @DavidvleggerWenher : Answer updated...Check back again..!

Comment: This 2nd one method will redirect your user before refreshing the page i.e just right when he clicks on refresh button or reload..!

Comment: It's OK..If you selected another answer...I suppose your problem will be solved then..!