# Log out page on page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I want to logout from my application on page refresh using ajax(already created) when user clicks refresh button from browser,user presses ctrl+f5,ctrl+r, back button on browser. I tried using event keycode but it did'nt worked for me. Can some one suggest something on how to do it.

Comment: See if this answer helps you https://stackoverflow.com/a/36444134/87972

Comment: Thanks @Hoa it worked for me.