# window.performance.navigation.type works in IE and Firefox but NOT in CHROME

Tags: javascript, jquery, reload

I have been trying to implement a functionality when the page refreshes. I figured that value of

```
    window.performance.navigation.type
```

turns 1 if the page reloads else, it is 0. I created an alert message on page load and the values are correct for IE and Firefox but it remains "0" for Chrome throughout no matter how many times the page reloads. I have also tried windows.onbeforeunload as per other stackoverflow answers but nothing seems to work!

How do I resolve this?

OR

Is there another way to detect a page reload that works on all the browsers?

Thanks!

Comment: Chrome does not support this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PerformanceNavigation

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if page gets reloaded or refreshed in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004978/check-if-page-gets-reloaded-or-refreshed-in-javascript)

Comment: @Dekel odd isn't this the [doc api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/navigation) says chrome 10 + support? **edit nvm that's the parent info**

Comment: @Andrei, Gsm added an answer regarding this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the docs, the [`Performance.navigation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/navigation) property returns a [`PerformanceNavigation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PerformanceNavigation) object.

Checking the [browsers compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PerformanceNavigation#Browser_compatibility) at the bottom of the page you can see that chrome is not supported.

Comment: Thanks @Dekel, But any other solution that you are aware of?

Comment: Can you explain what exactly is the functionality you are looking for?

Comment: Hi @Dekel, I am trying to navigate to another page when the page reloads. So, first I tried to figure out if it is a 'reload' using the value of performance.Navigation.type and then used location href to navigate to another page. It worked on IE and Firefox but not on Chrome. It would be helpful to get a solution that works on all browsers.

Answer (score 7):

As of 2017-11-01, Chrome (61.0.3163.100) does support the performance.navigation API. See [this gist](https://gist.github.com/conorgil/da0f931c23d35eede0033e261bc7e7e6) for some sample code that you can throw into a page and see it working.

I cannot find the Chromium ticket tracking the development, but [this Chromium blog post](https://blog.chromium.org/2017/09/chrome-62-beta-network-quality.html) links to the W3 spec that defines the performance.navigation API, so perhaps it was supported fully in a recent release.