# How do i detect if a browser(chrome) window is refreshed or closed?

Tags: javascript

This code works fine but worked in IE,I need in google chrome thanks.

```
    var isRefresh;
    function detectRefresh(){
     try
     {
       if(window.opener.title == undefined){
         isRefresh = true;
         document.write('Window was refreshed!');
       }
     }
     catch(err)
     {
       isRefresh = false;
       document.write('Window was closed!');
     } 
   }
```

Comment: add event listener for `beforeunload` event.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/beforeunload

Comment: Check this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004978/check-if-page-gets-reloaded-or-refreshed-in-javascript

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if page gets reloaded or refreshed in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004978/check-if-page-gets-reloaded-or-refreshed-in-javascript)

Comment: Hi all, I tried all the above didn't worked in chrome thanks for your concern.