# go to a specific controller before loading a state in angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

When my website is loaded I want to be redirected to a specific state. I do it with the following code.

```
angularRoutingApp.run(function ($rootScope, $state, $location, $transitions) {
    $transitions.onStart({}, trans = > {
        $state.go('menuNeurolengua', trans.targetState())
    });
}
```

But I throw this problem:

[image]

How can I solve that?

Comment: Normally you would just accomplish "redirected to a specific state on load" with a default state.  This code will never work, since it is overriding *every transition, including the one that it is trying to use*, which will cause an endless loop.  Is there some specific reason that a default state isn't usable in your case?

Comment: @Claies I know. I simply want to learn how to do this, then take the example and make my necessary validations. Can you help me with this please?

Comment: @Claies I want to get some way to detect when the user reloads the web page directly from the browser, or with f5. when I do, I want to redirect it to a default state to force it to do the internal navigation of the page.

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004978/check-if-page-gets-reloaded-or-refreshed-in-javascript

Comment: @pegla it works. I will give you the best answer. post it please

Answer (score 0):

Since your only problem is finding out if user refreshed page or page was loaded, you could do something like this (make sure you inject $window):

```
if ($window.performance.navigation.type == 1) {
    console.info( "This page is reloaded" );
} else {
    console.info( "This page is not reloaded");
}
```

More explanation in this answer:
[Check if page gets reloaded or refreshed in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004978/check-if-page-gets-reloaded-or-refreshed-in-javascript)