# How to detect the Browser refresh and Close events in Angular JS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

*Hi  i have tried the below event to detect but sometimes it doesn't fire the event, while closing the tab or Browser.*

```
$window.onbeforeunload
```

Comment: this will help you:-https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004978/check-if-page-gets-reloaded-or-refreshed-in-javascript

Answer (score 1):

if you want only browser close do something and you do want when refresh page yuo can use this code:

```
   window.onbeforeunload = function () {
    if (performance.navigation.type == 1) {
        localStorageService.remove("authorizationData");
    }
}
```