# Preventing state from page reload

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

How do I prevent certain states from being loaded if application is opened from window reload/F5 key using AngularJs 1.6 and UI-Router with Html5 mode enabled.

Part of my UI-Router configuration:

```
.state("recordform", {
            url: "/form/:formid/:recordid",
            templateUrl: "Form.html",
        })
        .state("modalform", {
            parent: "RecordForm",
            url: "/modalform/:modalformid/:modalrecordid",
            templateUrl: "ModalForm.html"
        })
```

I need to prevent loading "modalform" state if page is opened by pasting link or F5 in browser.

The "modalform" state is opened in modal window which I don't want to open on page reload. The state should be accessible manually after refresh event is over.

I tried to check in "root" state if there is certain string in url but root seems to don't know about other states but himself.

I could also check in "modalform" controller if the state is opened from F5 but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Check this answer it will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004978/check-if-page-gets-reloaded-or-refreshed-in-javascript

Comment: I think the "performance.navigation.type" property will make it unable to reach the "modalform" state manually after refresh. I want discard the state only in the reload event. After that the state should be accessible.

Answer (score 1):

You can listen to the state change event (or implement a transition hook in newer version of UI router), and check for the existence of previous state.

The idea is that if a state is visited by a page refresh or URL paste, then the previous state will not exist.

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, options) {
  if (!fromState && toState.name === 'modalform') {
    event.preventDefault(); // Prevent access to the state

    // optionally redirect to other state if required
    $state.go("your_default_state");
  }
})
```

And, the `modalform` state will be accessible if it is navigated from any other state, because at that time, `toState` will exist.