# How to redirect to another url on refresh using JavaScript/(other easy alternatives)?

Tags: javascript, redirect, refresh

How to redirect to another url on page refresh or page back using JavaScript or (any other easy alternatives );

Answer (score 0):

You can combine the page capture via something like a navigator object shown here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/36444134/3187487

And then use `window.location` to redirect the person to where ever you want from there.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this perhaps:

```
if (window.performance) {
  console.info("window.performance works");
}
  if (performance.navigation.type == 1) {
    window.location.href = "https://www.example.com"
  }
```

[Ref1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004978/check-if-page-gets-reloaded-or-refreshed-in-javascript/36444134#36444134), [Ref2](https://appendto.com/2016/04/javascript-redirect-how-to-redirect-a-web-page-with-javascript/)