# React Router | load component only on page refresh

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, page-refresh

I'm using `React Router v4` [Browser Router](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/BrowserRouter). My scenario is I have call login page on every page refresh (Browser Refresh click or F5)

**Route**

```
 <Router history={history}>
        <div>
          <Spin spinning={this.props.isloading}>
            <Switch>
              <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
              <Route path="/Dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
              <Route path='*' component={NotFound} />
            </Switch>
          </Spin>
        </div>
      </Router>
```

I need to load login component on page refresh so I need something like below

```
<Refresh path="/login" component={Login} />
```

Comment: I think I answered your question; however, I honestly can't understand why you'd ever want to detect if the user refreshes the page. If I reloaded a page and the page displayed something differently, not because there's an update, but because I clicked refresh, I feel like that behavior diminishes the user experience somewhat.

Answer (score 2):

It happens to me and the issue was i am importing **Router** from react-router-dom instead of **BrowserRouter as Router**.

Answer (score 0):

Create a `componentDidMount` method in your root component, which will be responsible for logging in your user by redirecting the user to `/login`.

Then add a event listener for page refresh which will logout the user for any page refresh.

```
componentDidMount(){
    if(!userLoggedIn()){
        //redirect to login
        history.push("/login")
    }

    window.addEventListener('beforeunload', logoutTheUser);
    /* if you are not maintaining a session, you dont need this
      as user will be logged out automatically on page refresh.*/
}
```

Comment: `window.addEventListener('beforeunload', logoutTheUser); `It is getting called even I switch pages. I need to call only on page refresh not on changing menus

Answer (score 0):

Just do something like:

```
const Refresh = ({reload, children}) => reload ? children : null;

...

<Refresh reload={performance.navigation.type === 1}>
    <Redirect to="/login"/>
</Refresh>
```

Based on:

- [Check if page gets reloaded or refreshed in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004978/check-if-page-gets-reloaded-or-refreshed-in-javascript)
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PerformanceNavigation

Comment: I added this in route but it is not redirecting to login

Comment: sorry, I misunderstood. I thought you wanted to change the routes themselves if the page was reloaded. to do a redirect, you just have to render the Redirect component from React Router

Comment: `<Redirect to="/login" />` How I use it for every page refresh?

Comment: Just render that snippet every time. It'll only conditionally render the redirect if the page has been refreshed