# How to know if a tab is closed?

Tags: javascript

I'm actually trying to find some solution to see if the tab of the site was closed and store it on `localStorage`, I'm using `onunload` and `onbeforeunload` for this scenario but the problem is that if I refresh/reload (`ctrl+r`) or press the `f5` button the value will set to true.

Comment: yes, because f5 unloads then loads ... there's no way to distinguish

Comment: module? api? you've totally lost me

Comment: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004978/check-if-page-gets-reloaded-or-refreshed-in-javascript) might be helpful ..?

Comment: @JaromandaX https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PerformanceNavigation Though not widely supported, yet.

Answer (score 0):

You could un-set the value by determining if the page was indeed refreshed. When the site is closed, save the time at which the site was closed in local storage. When the page loads, compare the current time to the saved time and if it's "too recent", set the value to false.

Comment: [This](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PerformanceNavigation) is much easier ...

Comment: It sure is! I trusted the above comment about "no way to distinguish". Turns out there is.

Comment: indeed, @BrettCommandeur, sorry for misleading you, I'm sure the *not widely supported* solution is better than nothing