# JavaScript - How to know if web-page load for the first time, or after a refresh?

Tags: javascript, page-refresh

I would like to execute a JavaScript function after a web-page was refreshed (any way: F5 key, browser's refresh key, user re-enter same URL or any other method).
This method should be execute only after refresh, not after 1st page-load.

Something like:

```
window.onrefresh = function() { ... }; // of curse, onrefresh isn't real event
```

I find some solutions in the web, but none meet my needs:

### Dirty Flag

#### This method is simple, on load check flag - if flag not exist this is first load, else set the flag:

- Save flag in **local-storage**/**cookie**. The flag can be current Date/Time.
  If on-load flag not exist create it - this is first load. Else if flag exist compare it to current Date/Time - after refresh.
- Save the flag in the site URL. The flag will be '#' sign ('#' - will not change the site Navigation). Same as before on-load test if '#' exist at the end of the URL this is "refresh" load, else this is a first load - we need to add a '#' at the end of the URL.

### performance.navigation

The window object has this property: `window.performance.navigation.type` which can have 3 values:
0 - Page loaded due to link
1 - Page Reloaded
2 - Page loaded due to Back button
However this not working as expected. This value is always "1", on both first load and after refresh.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if page gets reloaded or refreshed in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004978/check-if-page-gets-reloaded-or-refreshed-in-javascript)

Comment: So `performance.navigation.type == performance.navigation.TYPE_RELOAD` is not working for you?

Comment: @epascarello, no it isn't and according to the specs you can test if back button was clicked, not the refresh button.

Comment: @GilEpshtain maybe you should post browser, OS and their versions in order to reproduce the issue with `performance.navigation.type == performance.navigation.TYPE_RELOAD` since for other devs it seems to work.

Comment: You could set a cookie on first load or a parameter at the window storage

Comment: have you tried Navigation Timing API.

Comment: @IswarKChettri - No can you please elaborate

Comment: might be useful in your case https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigation_timing_API. Here you can find `performance.navigation.type` which has value 1 when refresh....

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Navigation Timing API to gather performance data on the client side which you can then transmit to a server using XMLHttpRequest or other techniques. A `Performance` object offers access to the performance and timing-related information from the browser.

We can do so by using **Navigation Timing API**. The main interface of Navigation Timing API for your requirement is `performance.navigation.type` which checks the URL loaded in browser for the first time or it is loaded. Here is the sample.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>

    <script>
        if (window.performance) {
            alert("Browser Supports");
        }
        if (performance.navigation.type == 1) {
            alert("Reloaded"); 
        } else {
            alert("Not Reloaded"); 
        }
    </script>
 </head>
 <body>
    <h2>testing</h2>
 </body>
</html>
```

Hope it helps you