# How to call an Angular method when browser closes

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, session-cookies, angularjs-rootscope, auth0-lock

I'm relatively new in AngularJS and I have been asked to modify our application so that when the user closes the browser, we also log them out of Auth0 service.

I have the code below but I can't get it to fire. Kindly help.

```
$rootScope.$on("$destroy", function() {
    lockService.logout();
});
```

`lockService.logout()` holds the functionality that successfully logs out the user when they click `logout` button, including the `Auth0` `signout` function.

Somewhere I read that I can use the `$on.$destroy` of the main Controller but I am not sure how to do this. The above code is in fact inside the `mainController` function but it still doesn't work.

This is where I found my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36444134/1168597

Comment: can you try it with `$window.onbeforeunload` instead of `.$on('$destroy')`

Comment: yep, you can $window.onbeforeunload, then you will find out that angular can not send sync http requests and then later you will understand that requirements you were given is impossible to implement in reliable way.

Comment: @AlekseySolovey I have tried that. The problem with that is, it logs out even when you navigate between pages as the `$window.onbeforeunload` hits every time you navigate away, even within the app itself. So it's not a solution.

Comment: @SollyM it **shouldn't**. My guess is that your app reloads pages after navigation. AngularJS is for SPAs and should not refresh. `ngRoute` or `ui.router` will handle it correctly. Here is a small demo: [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/2A6C4fRdxsqUuWqO8EP6?p=preview)

Comment: @AlekseySolovey - Although this doesn't resolve my problem 100%, it has given me a direction and a temporary solution. The problem above is that, even when you refresh the page, the method executes. I only need to execute a piece of code when one closes the window.

Comment: @SollyM I'm not familiar with `onbeforeunload` that much, but maybe you can combine events and execute some code if another one fires

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a much cleaner and more effective approach.

```
$rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function () {

    if (!($window.performance.navigation.type === 1) && lockService.isAuthenticated()) {
        $rootScope.logout();
    }

});
```

So here if `window.performance.navigation.type` is `1`, it means the page was `refresh`-ed. What I do then is if it is not refreshed AND my `lockService.isAuthenticated()` returns true, I `logout` the user.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a directive like this to your body element.

```
<body body-unload></body>

app.directive('bodyUnload', [
    function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            replace: false,
            link: function (scope, element) {
                function cleanupApp(){
                 // do cleanup here
                }
                element[0].onbeforeunload = function() {
                        cleanupApp();
                };
            }
        };
    }
]);
```

Comment: Hi. I tried this. I created a file called `app.directive.js` in the `app\shared` then used a `script` tag to link to the file and then added the `body-unload` directive to the `body` tag. In the `cleanupApp()` method I added an `alert` and `cookie.delete` but none of those execute. Did I do anything wrong?