# Add a $ symbol next to number

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey

I have this script for tamper-monkey and the script is for amazon I just want to know how to put a $ symbol next to the number thing so it looks like real money is getting into my account.

```
    var oof = document.getElementById("gc-ui-balance-gc-balance-value");

var lastCount = localStorage.getItem("lastCount");

oof.innerHTML = lastCount || "500";

function animateValue(id) {
    var obj = document.getElementById(id);
    var current = parseInt(obj.innerHTML);

    setInterval(function () {
        var nextCount = current++;
        localStorage.setItem("lastCount", nextCount);
        obj.innerHTML = nextCount;
    }, 0.1);
}

animateValue('gc-ui-balance-gc-balance-value')
})();
```

Comment: "Related" user: https://stackoverflow.com/q/55127520

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
var oof = document.getElementById("gc-ui-balance-gc-balance-value");

var lastCount = localStorage.getItem("lastCount");

oof.innerText = '$' + lastCount + '.00' || "$500.00";

function animateValue(id) {
    var obj = document.getElementById(id);
    var current = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("lastCount")) || 500;

    setInterval(function () {
        var nextCount = current++;
        localStorage.setItem("lastCount", nextCount);
        obj.innerText = '$' + nextCount + '.00';
    }, 0.1);
}

animateValue('gc-ui-balance-gc-balance-value')
})();
```

Comment: When I tested it out it just says "NaN" where the money should be

Comment: @Jmuse.v2 OK I updated it, see if that works.  Adding a string to a number should work on its own but I'm not familiar with the environment you're in

Comment: Ok I made one more change, try changing innerHTML to innerText

Comment: I am still getting the "$NaN"

Comment: Yeah for sure!  If you want it to look even more real, you should add a .00 at the end of the number so it looks like its supposed to haha

Comment: Adding the ".00" does not work but it's ok. Thank you very much for helping me today kind person! :)

Comment: haha yeah no problem!  and it would work if you changed the code very slightly.  I could edit the answer one more time if you like.

Comment: No it's okay! Thanks Again!

Comment: Again Thank You Very Much @Chris Sandvik I will give you the link of the finished product! But you need tampermonkey to use it on amazon.       https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/379923-advanced-amazon-money-hack

Comment: @Jmuse.v2 by the way, I couldn't help myself.  I edited it one more time to include the decimals.  And it will work guaranteed this time, if you wish to use it.