# Detect if the page has been refreshed/ Reloaded

Tags: javascript, html, jsf

I developed a solution which detect when the page is being unload, using on `beforeUnload` JS function, the code works fine but I need to do some modifications based in the actions of the user, for instance if the user reload/refresh the page, I need to avoid The code execution inside the `onBeforeUnload`.

Is there a way to do that? I mean many other solutions propose to use `onBeforeUnload` which I’m using but I need to differentiate between the deifferents events that trigger the `onBeforeUnload` call.

Comment: Take a look at this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/55087265/5066625

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if page gets reloaded or refreshed in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004978/check-if-page-gets-reloaded-or-refreshed-in-javascript)

Comment: @MiroslavGlamuzina I tried that method but i need to get the action that the user just performed, with that method i'm getting a "Delay" for example if the user just refresh the page i'm getting "navigate" which is the action that the user performed before the reload, i need to get the action that the user just performed in that moment before the page is unloaded.