# How to detect that page has been reloaded Reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

There is stepper of pages with steps 1 2 3. If a page reloads on the second or third step, it has to redirect to the first step.

How can I detect that page has been reloaded?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if page gets reloaded or refreshed in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004978/check-if-page-gets-reloaded-or-refreshed-in-javascript)

Comment: where are you storing your page number variable? If it is memory then it would always get reinitialised at the page reload.

Comment: At the moment page number variables are not storing. Only redirect to the next page is using

Answer (score 1):

You can catch page load when `componentDidMount` of your root component is fired :

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    // do something
  }

}
```

Comment: How can I detect in componentDidMount that page has been reloaded?

Comment: just put the code you want to execute when the page is reloaded in  componentDidMount and react will run this function everytime the app is realoaded

Comment: The problem is how to detect that page is reloaded

Comment: Pass a prop from page 1 to page 2 to page 3, etc. If that prop is present, the page wasn't reloaded. If it is it's missing, that means the page was reloaded, and redirect the user