# Remove $location search on page refresh/reload in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to clear the stateParams (search parameters) from Url if a user reloads the page or refreshes it. I am using AngularJS 1.5.8.

I can detect the reload/refresh event and can even output to console, but the code to remove the search parameters doesn't fire. Here's what I am using

```
var windowElement = angular.element($window);
windowElement.on('beforeunload', function (event) {
    $location.url($location.path());
    console.info("page refreshed." + $location.path());        
});
```

Any pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps others, As none of the suggestions I saw on SO worked. I managed to create kind of a hack to get this working using the following code in **app.run** function.

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
    //not coming from any other page + coming to ads page + contains query string
    if (fromState.name == "" && toState.name == "current_page" && toState.url !== "/current-page-url") {
        $location.search({});
    }
});
```

What it does is if I come to the page from other pages, it will have fromState populated but when I reload the current page, the fromState will have no data and toState will the details of the current page. To avoid continuous looping, I also check if the current url contains any querystring.

**UPDATE**
Even a better solution. Found some help from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004978/check-if-page-gets-reloaded-or-refreshed-in-javascript).

```
$rootScope.$on("$locationChangeStart", function (event, next, current) {
        //Page reload detection
        if (next == current && && performance.navigation.type == 1) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $location.search({});
        }
    });
```

The first solution removes the query string even when you load a page with query string for the first time (via some bookmark).

The second solution works just as intended.

See this for reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/performance

Answer (score 2):

try

`$location.search({});`

to remove all params. If you want to remove specific ones, then

`$location.search('key', null);`

should do the trick.

Also, check out $destroy listener, which tells angular that on $destroy of a controller/directive, call this function.

```
$scope.$on('$destroy', function () {
   $location.search({});
});
```

Not much in the docs...but it's [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#event-$destroy).

Comment: Tried $location.search({}); as well. But the code only fires when we close the browser window but not on page reload. The weird thing is that the console output is logged both at refresh/reload as well as browser close events.