# call a method when page is refreshed in .html file in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, frontend

in my .html file in angular js i have this , but i] now it calls method checkIsActive() unlimited and got memory issue, but i want to call checkIsActive only when the page is refreshed. how can i specify that method checkIsActive should be called only each time page is refreshed

```
  >  <html>
    >         , <div   id ="test"  ng-if="checkIsActive()" class="sticky-icon-bar">  
    >         > </div>
    >     </html> ,, ,, ,, ,,,,
<div></div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if page gets reloaded or refreshed in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004978/check-if-page-gets-reloaded-or-refreshed-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

You are using `ng-if` which will call your function every time on DOM change. you have to use `ng-init` which will call only once on you page load.

You can try this way:-

```
<html>
  <div   id ="test"  ng-init="checkIsActive()" class="sticky-icon-bar">
  </div>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i changed my code to call the method in ng-init, now how i check the return value of that method? because i want if the return value of that method is false then i do not show that sticky-icon-bar. do i need to add ng-if also?

Comment: You can set scope variable on your method and use ng-if to show/hide your bar.