# How to redirect the user when he triggers the refresh button?

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress

So my question is simple. All I would like to know is how to redirect the user to a specific link when he refreshes the page (is that even possible)? I need it for a WordPress project. Thanks in advance.

Comment: there is really no way to know if they hit refresh button or are leaving the page. There are ways to detect it on the page load if it was a refresh.

Comment: Now that I think about it. It's logic, so there is no way I guess...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004978/check-if-page-gets-reloaded-or-refreshed-in-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

input type="button" value="Reload Page" onClick="document.location.reload(true)"

Comment: it adds a refresh button

Answer (score 0):

Its simple, you have to use sessions for this purpose.
At the start of the page u have to set a session variable when the user visits the page for the first time. 
Once the user visits that page that session variable will get set, the on the same page u have to check if that session variable is set or not, if its set that means user is trying to reload the site and that time u can redirect him.

Given below is the code

```
// Starting session
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION["visited"])){
    // redirect the user
}
else{
$_SESSION["visited"] = true;
}
```

**Note*** 
Also make sure that u destroy the session when user visits some other page of the site. Other wise page will always gets redirected untill session is destroyed.