# Which event to fire on close browser window/tab but do not fire on reload?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I would like to logout user immediately on close browser window.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
    if (user.isLoggedIn && expireOnCloseWindow) {
      user.logout();
    }
};
```

The event works OK for close window/tab, the event is fired and user is logged out. But event will fire also on page reload, what I want to prevent.

Does exists any way for logout on window close but prevent logout on page reload?

**Edit1:** It seems to be that performance.navigation is set after load the page and on beforeunload event is still with the same performance.navigation.type value.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<script>
    window.onbeforeunload = function () {
        let navOnject = performance.navigation;
        console.log(navOnject);

        if(navOnject.type !== navOnject.TYPE_RELOAD) {
            console.log('not reload');
        } else {
            console.log('reload');
        }
        return '';
    };
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if page gets reloaded or refreshed in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004978/check-if-page-gets-reloaded-or-refreshed-in-javascript)

Comment: @DamianKociszewski Thank you, I'm goying to try...

Comment: @DamianKociszewski ...not helped :-(, please check Edit1 in my post