# Detect refresh event in javascript

Tags: javascript

Is there any way in javascript to deactivate a button is the current page is refreshing / reloading? I want to deactivate some buttons when the user presses F5 / Refresh the page and I don't know if there is any way to verify is this event is ongoing. I want to add this validation when the user clicks the button:

```
<button onclick="if(IS_REFRESH_ONGOING) return false;">Button</button>
```

Comment: does this help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004978/check-if-page-gets-reloaded-or-refreshed-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

Use the [beforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/beforeunload_event) Event.

```js
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", ()=>{
   // Add your disable button code here
});
```