# How to detect a page refresh using javascript on APEX?

Tags: oracle-apex, refresh, ape

My goal is to do some javascript action the moment the user clicks the browser's refresh button.

I've tried:

**Function and Global Variable Declaration**

```
function pageunload(){
alert('here');
};
```

**Execute when Page Loads**

```
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', pageunload);
```

I know that the 'addEventListener' is working properly but the event is not the right one.

I have also tried to dynamic action "before Refresh", but I haven't been able to associate it to the page level, only items/regions etc.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if page gets reloaded or refreshed in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004978/check-if-page-gets-reloaded-or-refreshed-in-javascript)

Comment: What sort of JS would this activity invoke?

Comment: @KoenLostrie It's not exactly what I was looking for, but enabled me to solve my issue. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

In the page attribute you can write Javascript on Page Load which will be executed when the page is reloaded or submitted.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

beforeunload is the opposite of what you want

- Use the load event
- Check Mohamad image
- Create a dynamic action for page Load