# How to detect Close Tab/ Browser for logout in javascript vue.js with quasar framework

Tags: javascript, vue.js, quasar-framework

I want to call the logout function on the close tab or close the browser only, not on the refresh page.
I tried with the below example code it doing logout on the close tab perfectly but also doing logout if I refresh the page. 
I want to prevent logout on the refresh page.

```
 window.addEventListener('beforeunload', this.logout)
```

Comment: Hi, You can see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004978/check-if-page-gets-reloaded-or-refreshed-in-javascript

Comment: @YashMaheshwari, I went to that link but it doesn't work for me. I just need to call logout only if we can detect Close Tab OR Close Browser event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the below code in mounted() function and it works for me

```
 window.addEventListener("beforeunload", (event) => {
      // on the navigation type checking refresh or close tab/browser for logout

      console.log("performance.navigation.type " + performance.navigation.type);

      if (performance.navigation.type != 1) {
        this.logout();
      }
      return false;
    });
```