# How to get check if a page gets reloaded with js

Tags: javascript, refresh

How do you now check if a page gets reloaded?

It used to be like this:

```js
//check for Navigation Timing API support
if (window.performance) {
  console.info("window.performance works fine on this browser");
}
console.info(performance.navigation.type);
if (performance.navigation.type == performance.navigation.TYPE_RELOAD) {
  console.info( "This page is reloaded" );
} else {
  console.info( "This page is not reloaded");
}
```

But now I found out that navigation type is deprecated:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/navigation

So then I checked the replacement: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PerformanceNavigationTiming

Even after reading it it's still not very clear on how I could accomplish this. So how does the new way work of checking if a page gets refreshed?

I also tried this after I had read it:

```js
    if (PerformanceNavigationTiming.type == "reload") {
    alert('page reloaded')
    }
```

But then the alert won't be displayed.

And after that I tried this:

```js
    if (PerformanceNavigationTiming.type == PerformanceNavigationTiming.TYPE_RELOAD) {
    alert('page reloaded')
    }
```

But then It would display the alert also without a page refresh.

Then the last thing I tried:

```js
  const pageAccessedByReload = (
      (PerformanceNavigationTiming && PerformanceNavigationTiming.TYPE === 1) ||
        window.performance
          .getEntriesByType('navigation')
          .map((nav) => nav.type)
          .includes('reload')
    );
    
    alert(pageAccessedByReload);
```

But this also gives me an alert either false when it's not reloaded and true when it is reloaded. And I only want that alert when the page is reloaded.

Comment: Did you read [check-if-page-gets-reloaded-or-refreshed-in-javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004978/check-if-page-gets-reloaded-or-refreshed-in-javascript/53307588#53307588)?

Comment: That won't work since performance.navigation.type  is deprecated

Comment: So i guess you didn't read it, even now.

Comment: That I have to use PerformanceNavigationTiming.type is known to me yes. But it was not clear to me that you only literally had to replace the words from performance.navigation.type to PerformanceNavigationTiming. As I didnt see that written down anywhere litteraly just like that.

Comment: Yes you are right, thats weird...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You must remember to always pay attention when reading a new API docs, type in PerformanceNavigationTiming is a string and not a number so the correct way would be:

```js
if (window.PerformanceNavigationTiming) {
  console.info("window.performance works fine on this browser");
  
  if (PerformanceNavigationTiming.type === "reload") {
    console.info("This page is reloaded");
  } else {
    console.info("This page is not reloaded");
  }
}
```

Comment: PerformanceNavigationTiming.type will be always undefined as it is an interface and not a class

Answer (score 4):

From [MDN reference 2022: Navigation Timing Level 2 specification](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PerformanceNavigationTiming/type)

```
const navigationType = 
    (window.performance.getEntriesByType('navigation')
        [0] as PerformanceNavigationTiming).type;

const isPageReload = navigationType === 'reload';
const isNavigation = navigationType === 'navigate';
const isBackForwarad = navigationType === 'back_forward';
const isPrerender = navigationType === 'prerender';
```

Answer (score -1):

I have finally found a solution:

```js
  const pageAccessedByReload = (
      (PerformanceNavigationTiming && PerformanceNavigationTiming.TYPE === 1) ||
        window.performance
          .getEntriesByType('navigation')
          .map((nav) => nav.type)
          .includes('reload')
    );
    
    if (pageAccessedByReload == true) {
    alert(pageAccessedByReload);
  }
```

Now it will only show when the page is refreshed.