# Is it possible for us on javascript to detect on the event beforeunload/unload if its a refresh or leave?

Tags: javascript, onbeforeunload, onunload, unload

// This might seem to be a duplicate question, but all the questions I have found were old and was wondering if there is any new functionality available in the latest browsers

Requirement: Identify if the user has refreshed or reloaded the page
on the event "beforeunload" or "unload".

Comment: Why would you need this? I mean, if the user is leaving for a site out of your control, there's not much you can do...

Comment: I've found this answer that seems to answer what you are after
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004978/check-if-page-gets-reloaded-or-refreshed-in-javascript

Comment: The answer in the link is 11 years old. i had gone through that answer. I thought after so long the latest browsers might have some thing that can directly say if it was a reload or leave