# How can I load next page and run animation on that page with one click?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

So the thing is that I want to click a button on ./page.html so it opens ./index.html and the animation starts.

1. Pages are same domain
2. I don't want animation to start every time I open the ./index.html only when I click the button
3. I'd like it to be vanilla JS solution but jquery is ok

the main problem I can't solve is that I trigger button with specific id and the console says "Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')"

In other words in ./index.html I have a nav bar with links but one of the sections mentioned in nav bar is already present in ./index.html so I decided to highlight it with animation when I click that link. On ./page.html I still have same nav bar with same links (surprise) but this time I want when I click that button to open ./index.html first and then play the animation to highlight that section

I tried different solutions including setting a delay, using localStorage and iframe but none of these worked for me (or I was using them wrong)

Here's the minimization of the code

**./index.html** (section with class skills is the element where I want the animation to play)

```
        <nav>
           <a id="skills-button-main"  class="buttons corner-nav" href="#">skills</a>
        </nav>

         <section class="skills" id="skills-panel">
         </section>
```

**./page.html** (button that I want to click so the animation on ./index.html plays)

```
     <nav>
        <a id="skills-button-projects" class="buttons" href="./index.html">skills</a>
     </nav>
```

**JS** (this is how I make animation play every time I click on #skills-button-main in ./index.html)

```
if(document.getElementById("skills-button-main")){
$("#skills-button-main").click(function() {
    const el = $("#skills-panel").addClass("skills-animation");
    setTimeout(function() {
        el.removeClass("skills-animation");
    }, 2000);
})};
}
```

**JS** (this is one of the variation I tried to do same thing but with loading ./index.html page first)

```
if (document.getElementById("skills-button-projects")){ 
    document.getElementById("skills-button-projects").addEventListener("click", function() {   
    window.location.href = "./index.html";
    if(document.getElementById("skills-button-main")){
        $("#skills-button-main").click(function() {
            const el = $("#skills-panel").addClass("skills-animation");
            setTimeout(function() {
                el.removeClass("skills-animation");
            }, 2000);
        })};
    });
}
```

I'm using if statement at start because it's the same .js file so the script runs even if ID's doesn't exist on current html

Please somebody help

Answer (score 1):

i hope this answer could help you.

with `document.referrer` you can get previous page that refer you to current page.
and with `performance.navigation.type` you can check that page was not reloaded.

> `window.performance.navigation` property is deprecated and you can use this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53307588/10749726) to improve your code if you want . i did not use it for a simpler answer.

```
window.addEventListener('load', ()=>{
const section = document.getElementById('skills-panel');
if(!performance.navigation.type && document.referrer.includes('/page.html')){
  section.classList.add('add')
  section.addEventListener('animationend', ()=>{
  section.classList.remove('add')
   })
  }
})
```

i put the whole codes on [animateafterload.w3spaces.com](https://animateafterload.w3spaces.com/)