# I can't detect location reloaded in JS

Tags: javascript, browser, window

I can't check browser location reloaded in js ?

I tried [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004978/check-if-page-gets-reloaded-or-refreshed-in-javascript) but it doesn't work because [performence type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PerformanceNavigation/type) not work anymore in any browser.

I tried that code. But it doesn't work.

```js
if (window.performance) {
  console.info("window.performance works fine on this browser");
}
if (performance.navigation.type == performance.navigation.TYPE_RELOAD) {
  console.info("This page is reloaded");
} else {
  console.info("This page is not reloaded");
}
```

Comment: tested the above in chrome and worked fine.

Comment: `performance.getEntriesByType("navigation")[0].type`

Comment: @epascarello   Hacimov-dev & Somebody at it again -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76464368/how-can-i-divide-an-array-into-equal-sized-chunks-in-javascript/76464955#76464955

Answer (score 0):

I recommended to you use this:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(event) {
  var message = 'Are you sure you want to reload this page?';

  // Check if the event is a location reload
  if (event.currentTarget.performance && event.currentTarget.performance.navigation.type === 1) {
    // The current page is being reloaded
    // Perform your desired actions here
    console.log('Page is being reloaded');
  }

  // You can also display a confirmation message
  return message;
};
```

Comment: Was this copied from somewhere? The (original) lead was completely out of whack with the text in the code comments. [ChatGPT](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned) plagiarism? Ordinary plagiarism?