# how to detect browser refresh before page reloads

Tags: typescript, browser

I am using the `beforeunload` event to detect when the browser is reloaded and when it is closed.

To detect if the browser reloads, I am using the following line of code:

```
window.performance.getEntriesByType('navigation').map((nav) => (nav as any).type).includes('reload')
```

The problem is that the previous line detects the reload when the browser page has already loaded, I need to detect the reload in the `beforeUnload` event before reloading the page. Does anyone know how to do it, or is it impossible?

I tried with many solutions that I found but none of them worked, they all detect the browser refresh after loading the page. Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if page gets reloaded or refreshed in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004978/check-if-page-gets-reloaded-or-refreshed-in-javascript)

Comment: You can’t know that at that time