# JS difference between enter page and refresh page

Tags: javascript, browser

Is it possible to detect situation when page is **entered** and when the same page is **refreshed**

```
if (entered) alert("hi");
if (refreshed) alert("you've refreshed");
```

Somehow there are some little differences between page rendering when entered and when refreshed and it would be much easier to detect the case than to debug it for me (if its even possible - maybe some browser optimization stuff is causing it).

Comment: onunload set a cookie. Also look in the net tab of firefox with firebug or Chrome whn you load and reload

Comment: when someone will leave page and enter it after a while it will be treated as refresh

Answer (score 1):

This isn't an ideal solution, but if your page can load in under 5 seconds than this will work, and assuming you are not navigation to another page, then returning within 5 seconds.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(){
  window.sessionStorage.setItem('lastvisit', new Date().getTime());
}

var lastVisit = +window.sessionStorage.getItem('lastvisit');

var isRefresh = (new Date().getTime() - lastVisit) < 5000;
console.log(isRefresh);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no perfect way of tracking reloads verses new page loads but this solution works in most situations. Use sessionStorage in combination with an unload event:

```
(function (win) {
  'use strict';
  var reloaded = false,
    ss = win.sessionStorage,
    offset = 1000, // 1 second, may need tweaking if
    // your page takes a long time to load/where
    // this code is located in your page
    now = function () {
    return (new Date()).getTime();
    },
    lastUnload = ss.getItem('lastunload'),
    loadStatus = document.getElementById('status');

  // sessionStorage returns null if nothing was stored
  if (lastUnload !== null) {
    // sessionStorage returns a string, +lastUnload
    // coerces the string held in lastUnload into an integer
    // see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#-_.28Unary_Negation.29
    if (+lastUnload + offset > now()) {
        reloaded = true;
    }
  }

  win.addEventListener('unload', function () {
    ss.setItem('lastunload', now());
  }, false);

  if (lastUnload === null) {
    loadStatus.innerHTML = 'First visit of session.';
  } else if (reloaded) {
    loadStatus.innerHTML = 'Page was reloaded.';
  } else {
    loadStatus.innerHTML = 'Navigated back to page after leaving';
  }

}(window));
```

This code defines a page reload as returning to the page within 1 second of leaving it, so there could be false positives if someone leaves the page and immediately hits the back button but with normal browsing behavior that really shouldn't happen. You can modify the `offset` variable if you want to give more or less leeway, but 1 second seems to be a good default.

After developing this code I also found this [similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/568977/identifying-between-refresh-and-close-browser-actions/13916847#13916847).

Comment: Essentially yes, I've been working on it for a while, didn't see your answer until afterward. Would have posted it a long time ago if I didn't try to call `addEventListener` from `document` instead of `window`... that's the problem with working with DOM libraries all the time you forget the basics convoluted DOM API.

Answer (score -1):

If `sessionStorage` is available, you can use that.

```
if (!window.sessionStorage.getItem('visited')) {
    //entered
    window.sessionStorage.setItem('visited', true);
}
else {
    //refreshed
}
```

[More on `sessionStorage`](http://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/#the-sessionstorage-attribute)

Comment: I don't think this will solve the OP's problem, this will return true for both a refresh and coming in from another page as long as the user was on the page before

Comment: @JustinBicknell you're incorrect.  Did you actually test it?  You can do it simply: open the console, write something to session storage.  Check its value.  Refresh.  Check its value.  Copy URL and open a new tab, open the console, and check the same value.

Comment: I've tested it, pasted code to .js file and refreshed page, it has showed 'enter'... and then, no matter if I was refreshing or entering it (also other pages with same .js included) it was showing 'refreshed'. Maybe it depends on server/system/browser?

Comment: I just tested it, and it behaves the way I initially thought it would.  make sure you are in the same tab, run the code, refresh, click away, go to the original page, it says refreshed even though it was not a refresh.  The first time you do this it works, but after two times it always says refreshed.

Comment: @OPOPO it may depend on the browser .. it depends on the browsing *context* as well.  I only tested in Chrome, which considers the same window to be the browsing context; I think this makes sense.  If you are talking about someone leaving your site and then coming back to it, that is different -- if they are just navigating on your own site, though, you can always change the `sessionStorage` values on other pages

Comment: According to the [Mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Storage#sessionStorage): `Opening a page in a new tab or window will cause a new session to be initiated.` So opening it in a new window/tab creates a new context. Navigating away to another page and navigating back to the page in the same tab would **not** create a new context even though it is not the same as a reload.

Comment: @UselessCode I wouldn't expect it to be a new context anyway, but I guess the OP wants to treat navigating away and back as an "entry."  I am saying that if the navigating away is to another page on his own website, he can change the `sessionStorage` value so that navigating back will count as an entry.  He obviously does not have that option if they navigate to another website, though -- he could perhaps check the history