# Differentiate between refresh and tab close browser in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, tabs, refresh

Is there any socket method or any other way to differentiate between tab close and refresh browser in node.js?

Comment: pls also tell the reason if you vote down..

Comment: your understanding is so wrong it's impossible to even say anything... Node.js is server side, there is no tabs or browser

Comment: yes node.js is server side. like 'disconnect' method is fired when we close the tab of browser or refresh the browser. I just want to differentiate between two.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Identifying Between Refresh And Close Browser Actions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/568977/identifying-between-refresh-and-close-browser-actions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to distinguish between browser tab close and browser tab refresh in node.js.
But i find a way via javascript. [Here](https://webkul.com/blog/detect-browser-tab-refresh-browser-tab-close-using-javascript/) it is

Comment: What if the user clicks on the "refresh" button in the browser bar?