# How to destroy session and cookies on browser close in rails 4

Tags: jquery, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to destroy user session and expire cookies whenever i close the browser. To expire cookies i try to create cookies without expiration time but not work.

**EDIT :**

```
cookies[:test] = {value: "test123", domain: :all}
```

I create this cookie and i want when i close the broswer , the is not available there . and when user log in i set current user with session (`session[:user_id= @user.id`) and I want when I close the browser , `session[:user_id]` should be null.

Comment: Please post some code to show your efforts first.

Comment: cookies[:test] = {value: "test123", domain: :all} . i create this cookie and i want when i close the broswer , the is not available there . and when user log in i set current user with session (session[:user_id= @user.id) and i want  when i close the browser , session[:user_id] should be nil.

Comment: @PardeepSaini I edited your answer. Please edit your answer when giving such informations, don't post code in comments. detail as much as you can your question.

Comment: @PardeepSaini : setting cookies without an expire time will be deleted once the **browser** (**not** the **tab** or **window**) is closed. Did you try to close the browser and checked for the existence of cookie in next request?

Comment: yes, checked everything. I close the browser and reopen but cookies are still there.

Comment: Usually browsers (Firefox and Chrome for sure) will delete such cookies (without an expire date) only if you fully close the browser (eg all tabs and windows). So solution proposed by @mr-h is a better option IMHO

Answer (score 1):

Just a quick suggestion:

I think if you use something like AngularJS or even jQuery, then you can fire a trigger when browser about to close to trigger a function to remove the cookies for you.

Regarding the Sessions you can use the same theory only you need to trigger Ajax as Session variables can be removed by Rails.

Comment: i try onbeforeload event but fire when we refresh page.

Comment: there are tricks to detect it. Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/568977/identifying-between-refresh-and-close-browser-actions