# How to differentiate browser close and refresh using angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have localstorage for employeeid stored.When i refresh the browser get local storage value like employeeid based on employeeid get some data .when i close the browser i want to clear employeeid in local storage by using angularjs or javascript. I tried the following code.

```
window.onunload = close;
    function close() {
        //// do something...
        localStorage.clear();
        return null;
    }
```

In the above code when i refresh the browser that time also window.onunload fired and clear the local storage values, but i want to clear local storage at the time of browser close only.

Comment: Do you need this to work across different windows/tabs? If not, you should use `sessionStorage` to begin with.

Comment: no only one single tab

Comment: Well then use `sessionStorage` – it only lives until the window/tab is closed.

Comment: Thank u @CBroe. Now my issue was solved using sessionStorage

Comment: OK, I added that as an answer, plus a little more context.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you do not need this to work across different windows/tabs, then you should use `sessionStorage` instead of `localStorage`.

Where what you store into `localStorage` is “permanent”, `sessionStorage` stores values only until the window/tab is closed, similar to a “session cookie”, that is set without any lifetime – that will live only until the browser is closed (but will be available across different tabs when your site is open in more than one.)

A few more details can be found in these questions:
[What is the difference between localStorage, sessionStorage, session and cookies?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19867599/1427878)
[HTML5 Local storage vs. Session storage](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5523140/1427878)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that's you're looking for [Identifying Between Refresh And Close Browser Actions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/568977/identifying-between-refresh-and-close-browser-actions)

Comment: That is also same problem at refresh browser that will be executed