# How to detect closing and refreshing browser tab?

Tags: javascript, typescript, dom-events

I know that this code will be triggered when you closing tab AND when you refresh the tab.

```
window.onbeforeunload = closingCode;
    function closingCode(e) {
        var evtobj = window.event ? event : e;

        var callDateUTC = { callDateUTC: new Date().toUTCString() };

        if (evtobj == e) {
            //firefox
            if (!evtobj.clientY) {
                that._apiGateway
                    .post(that._apiGateway.ApiPaths.RefreshToken, callDateUTC)
                    .subscribe((loginResponse: LoginResponse) => {
                    });
            }
        }
        else {
            //IE
            if (evtobj.clientY < 0) {
                that._apiGateway
                    .post(that._apiGateway.ApiPaths.RefreshToken, callDateUTC)
                    .subscribe((loginResponse: LoginResponse) => {
                    });
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
```

But I want to know which of those two event was triggered...

```
if (tabWasRefreshed){
    //code
}
else if(tabWasClosed){
    //code
}
```

Comment: Similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/568977/identifying-between-refresh-and-close-browser-actions

Comment: I found the answer, but this question is well structured.

Comment: I need to know that before the event.

Comment: Please don't edit answers into your question. Answers need to be posted in the "Your Answer" box below the question.